# how to call value $_POST['variable+array'] from name that contain array in input type

Tags: php, html, arrays, variables, post

iam a newbie, i have a problem with this code, please help.

```
<input type="text" id="hargautama<?php echo $row['idharga']; ?>" name="hargautama<?php echo $row['idharga']; ?>">
```

my problem is on this

```
if(isset($_POST['updatehargautama'])){
    
    $hargautama = $_POST['????'];
```

i want to insert this value to database from this input type

```
<input type="text" id="hargautama<?php echo $row['idharga']; ?>" name="hargautama<?php echo $row['idharga']; ?>">
```

thanks for the help guys. i owe u all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the form is submitted to the same page, you can modify your code like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['updatehargautama'])) {
    $idharga = $_POST['idharga'];
    $hargautama = $_POST['hargautama'.$idharga];

    // Now you have the value from the input field with the name 'hargautama<idharga>'
}?>

//Your HTML form
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="idharga" value="<?php echo $row['idharga']; ?>">
    <input type="text" id="hargautama<?php echo $row['idharga']; ?>" name="hargautama<?php echo $row['idharga']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="updatehargautama" value="Update">
</form>
```

In this code, I've added a hidden input field named "idharga" to store the value of $row['idharga']. When the form is submitted, it will send both the value from the input field with the name 'hargautama' and the 'idharga' value in the $_POST array. then access the 'idharga' value to construct the correct name of the input field and retrieve the corresponding value.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset($_POST['updatehargautama'])) 
{
       $idharga = $_POST['updatehargautama']; 
       $hargautama = $_POST['hargautama' . $idharga];
}
```